# Use of the word "Space" in a tag

Tags: discussion, tags

So far, we have the following tags with the word space in them:

[space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law)
[space-medicine](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-medicine)
[space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle)
[deep-space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-space)
[space-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-station)
[space-weather](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-weather)
[space-junk](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-junk)
[space-life](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-life)
[space-telescope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-telescope)
[space-elevator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-elevator)
[spacesuits](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacesuits)
[spacelab](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacelab)
[spacecraft-development](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacecraft-development)

I've probably missed a few, but you get the idea. This entire site is about space, so many of these are redundant. What should be our tag policy for using the word space?

Comment: Seems like there are enough variables that each tag should be considered separately.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: I would get the individual policy in place via this question, and deal with specific questions as they arise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the word space is critical to understanding the concept, and is always included when discussing it, it should be included. The following is an incomplete list of such terms:

- [space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle)
- [deep-space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-space)
- [space-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-station)
- [space-weather](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-weather)
- [space-junk](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-junk)
- [space-elevator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-elevator)
- [spacesuits](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacesuits)
- [spacecraft-development](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacecraft-development)

If the word space is simply used as an adjective, but the meaning is still clear without it, then we should remove it. Thus, the following should not use the word space (Will include the tag currently used, but in the future, space should be removed)

- [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law)
- [space-medicine](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-medicine)
- [space-life](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-life) (To replace this tag, I've been using [astronaut-lifestyle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronaut-lifestyle))
- [spacelab](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacelab)

Comment: Soo... Retag them with my awesome editing powers?

Comment: @Undo: Hold off for a bit, let's make sure there's a consensus.

Comment: Obviously. I wouldn't make *that* mistake again (referring to a rather embarrassing event on mSO) :)

Comment: The problem with space-law is that there's a tag for international-law, and meta question I posted had more votes for defining them as separate concepts than just having one law tag.  So can we keep it space-law?

Comment: here's the question: http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/5/tags-space-law-vs-international-law

Comment: space–life could be renamed into life-in–space

Comment: So 'space-junk' should be kept **and** be truncated to 'junk'?! Also, use of the 'life' tag seems to be weakly defined (only 3 questions involving "search for ET life", "T life survivability in ET environments", one that seems completely redundant with 'health'). What tag should be used for a question about ordinary human activity in space (what seems to fit trapo's proposed 'life-in-space', though a more distinct term might be better)?

Comment: @paul I agree, it made it to both lists... Oops...

Comment: I vote retag em all.

Answer (score 1):

Big issue ... in a lot of cases, the "space" prefix does refer to traditional terms (space shuttle) or accepted scientific disciplines (space law). Removing "space" would be rather strange.

In some cases, I can well imagine to talk not only about a space issue but also compare it to e.g. terrestrial counterparts of the same problem. Junk is a problem here on Earth as it is in space (lots of interesting analogies with international waters for instance). Weather can be relevant went talking about rocket launches and their delays, space weather is kind of something else. Ironically, in both cases people try to forecast, in both cases they often fail (big time).

So ... no matter how odd this is, but I vote for keeping the prefixes as long as the term is not 100% unique for space (cant think of any right now).

Answer (score 0):

For those topics that deal with one specific aspect of being "in space" a more specific prefix can be used.

For example, topics relating to the effects of reduced gravity on `X` have the form `reduced-gravity-X`

- [reduced-gravity-sports](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-sports)
- [reduced-gravity-manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-manufacturing)
- [reduced-gravity-cooking](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-cooking)