# Should [space-law] be just [law]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging, tagging

I was thinking of going through and retagging all the [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law) questions to just [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law). Before doing so, however, I decided to ask the community - It seems like there is something I am missing.

Should we go ahead with it, or is there something different about [space-law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-law)?

> **Note:** I'll take upvotes as votes *to* retag, and downvotes as votes *not* to retag.

Comment: As seen in http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/683/jurisdiction-over-crime-in-space there really is no "space law" (*currently*).

Comment: This looks like it has sufficient approval to move forward. I see here http://space.stackexchange.com/tags/space-law/synonyms that 'law' is still being remapped to 'space-law'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would hazard towards keeping them seperate. They are similar but i can see some small differences.

**SpaceLaw**: would refer to any questions regarding what happens when crime is commited whilst in the ships actually in space.

**Law**: This would refer to any and all questions about law whilst on Land. Be it on earth or other colonised planets (yeah im future proofing, but lets be honest itll happen eventually)

Space law would be used for some of the questions we already have such as the one about crimes committed on a ship.

Law could be used for questions that relate to space exploration but actually take place on land. e.g **could the people who launched a rocket from land be held accountable for damage / destruction of the satellite their rocket knocked out of orbit**

The differences here are that the one is space is outside any jurisdiction, and falls to the captain. whereas the ones that take place actually on land will be in a jurisdiction of some kind and are thus different

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all of the law tags should just be [law](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law). Fundamentally, this isn't a site about law, and drawing any distinction between the various possibilities of law isn't going to bring a person here or not. Fundamentally, this is a site about space, and unless the word "space" is required to make sense of the word ([space-junk](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-junk), for instance), then it should be removed from tags, per https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/25